# Prove that the boundary and the interior of a manifold are disjoint.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

What shown below is a reference from *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres.[image]

So using the last lemma I ask to prove that the boundary and the interior of a manifold are disjoint. In particular I attempted to show this using reductio ad adsurdum but it seems I didn't be able to do this. Anyway reading the above definition it seems that the boundary and the interior are disjoint by them own definition. Indeed there are two possible cases: either there exist a coordinate patch $\alpha$ about $p$ with domain an open set in $\Bbb R^k$ or there not exist a such coordinate patch. Perhaps is my last argument incorrect? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: You want to show that (b) and (c) cannot happen at the same time. Try to prove the following: Given two open subsets $U,V\subset [0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$, a diffeomorphism $\psi: U \rightarrow V$ takes the boundary to the boundary and the interior to the interior of $[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$. **Hint:** Removing an interior point creates a hole, but removing a boundary point doesn't.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand completely your hints: could you explain better, please?

Comment: Anyway reading the above definition it seems that the boundary and the interior are disjoint by them own definition. Indeed there are two possible cases: either there exist a coordinate patch $\alpha$ about $p$ with domain an open set in $\Bbb R^k$ or there not exist a such coordinate patch. Is my last argument incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely something to show: A priori it might be that for a given point $p\in M$ there exist two different charts - one that takes $p$ to the boundary of $\mathbb{H}^k=[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$ and one that takes it to the interior. We have to show that this is impossible.

Suppose we had such charts, denoted with $\varphi_i:U\rightarrow \mathbb{H}^k$ ($i=1,2$) for which $\varphi_1(p)\in \mathrm{int}\mathbb{H}^k$ and $\varphi_2(p)\in \partial\mathbb{H}^k$. Then there would be a small neighbourhood $V\subset \mathrm{int}\mathbb{H}^k$ around $x=\varphi_1(p)$ such that the composition $f = \varphi_2\circ\varphi_1^{-1}\vert_V:V\rightarrow f(V)\subset\mathbb{H}^k$ was a diffeomorphism onto its image. Then $f(x)\in \partial \mathbb{H}^k$, which is forbidden by the following Lemma:

**Lemma**. Suppose $V\subset \mathrm{int}\mathbb{H}^k$ is open and $f:V\rightarrow f(V)\subset \mathbb{H}^k$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image. Then $f(V)\cap \partial \mathbb{H}^d = \emptyset$.

This Lemma, depending on your point of departure, is definitely non-trivial. E.g. in Lee's smooth manifold book it is Excercise 7.7 and follows from the earlier Proposition 7.16, which asserts that $f$, viewed as map into $\mathbb{R}^k$, is open. But $f(V)$ is only an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ if it does not intersect $\partial \mathbb{H}^k$.

Another way of proving the Lemma is using algebraic topology - and this is what I alluded to in my comment about 'poking holes'. This might be a somehwat heavy gun for the situation at hand, but has the advantage that one can relax the requirement from $f$ being a diffeomorphism to it merely being a homeomorphism. The idea is as follows: Without loss of generality you can assume that $V$ is an open ball around $x$, but then $f\vert_{V\backslash x}:V\backslash x \rightarrow f(V)\backslash f(x)$ is a homeomorphism between a space which is homotopic to $S^{k-1}$ and a space which is  contractible. But this is impossible, as one can check e.g. by looking at homology groups.

Comment: Okay, unfortunately I did not yet study algebraic topology but I studied general topology. So could you prove the lemma using only general topology results?

Comment: Anyway using Munkres definition is not necessary to prove this: indeed it seems to me that it follows immediately by own definition that the a boundary point can't be an interior point, right? What can you say about?

Comment: I have read Munkres' definition more carefully and had a look into the book: Yes, the definition indeed defines the boundary as the complement of the interior. One then has to show that this is equivalent to the definition of a boundary point being one mapped to $\partial\mathbb{H}^k$ by a chart. This is precisely the content of Lemma 24.2c). It's proof hinges exactly on the Lemma from my answer, which follows from Munkres' Theorem 8.2. This is analogous to Lee's Proposition 7.16.

Comment: In any case I can recommend Lee's book to you which seems to be a bit more modern and is written very clearly.

Comment: I download Lee's book [here](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=FA272C5F93DF3D5CE040F54D3177DB89) but unfortunately I did not fint the proposition $7.16$ because probably what I downloaded is a more recent ediction so could you indicate me the page where I can find that proposition? Excuse me for the bother. Anyway thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Comment: In my version Proposition 7.16 is in the chapter on 'submersions' and is titled **Properties of Submersions**, that way you should be able to find it. It might also be useful to read his first introduction on manifolds with boundary in the first chapter.